# Can not display pre-filled list via the JQuery autocomplete method Laravel 5

Tags: jquery, laravel-5, autocomplete

I am unable to view the pre-populated drop-down list based on a value entered in the search field as the principle of google search:
excerpt view administration.blade.php

```
<form action="PrestationController@autocomplete" method="get" >
    <!-- Recherche -->
    <section class="panel panel-default">
        <header class="panel-heading">Recherche
            <input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword" class="form-control" placeholder="Rechercher">
        </header>
        <div class="panel-body">Autres imputs</div>
    </section>
</form>
```

extract overview app.blade.php

```
// header

<link href='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css' rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
{!! Html::script('js/administration.js') !!}
{!! Html::script('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js') !!}
```

Route file extract

```
Route::resource('administration', 'PrestationController');
```

Controller file extract

```
public function autocomplete(Request $request) {
    $term = $request->get('term'); //jQuery uses the word term
    $data = Prestation::where('libelle', 'LIKE', '%'.$term.'%')
        ->take(10)
        ->get();

    $results = array();
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $results[] = ['id' => $value->id, 'value' => $value->libelle];
    }
    return response()->json($results);
}
```

file Js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#keyword" ).autocomplete({
        source: '/administration',
        minlenght:1,
        autofocus:true,
        select:function(e, ui) {
            consolelog(ui);
        }
    });
});
```

I receive an answer in the console : 
GET http://localhost:8000/administration?term=desh 200 OK

Can you help me diagnose the problem? thank you

EDIT
Here my table with values
[table prestations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yA0hO.png)

and migration :

```
class CreatePrestationsTable extends Migration {
/**
* Run the migrations.
*
* @return void
*/
public function up()
{
//
Schema::create('prestations', function (Blueprint $table) {
$table->increments('id'); //identifiant
$table->string('categorie'); // catégorie de la prestation (30 caractères max)
$table->string('libelle')->unique(); // libellé unique de la prestation (100 caractères max)
$table->string('description'); // description de la prestation (250 caractères max)
$table->integer('unite_id')->unsigned(); // relation avec le référentiel des unités
$table->integer('catégorie_id')->unsigned(); // relation avec le référentiel des unités
$table->timestamps(); // horodatage de l'enregistrement
 });

Schema::table('prestations', function(Blueprint $table) {
$table->foreign('unite_id')->references('id')->on('unites')
$table->foreign('categorie_id')->references('id')->on('categories')
->onDelete('restrict')
->onUpdate('restrict');
});
}

public function down()
{
Schema::drop('prestations');
}
}
```

Comment: Does you have any error message?

Comment: No error message. My table has values yet. The drop down list is blank. I think it lacks some code in my controller. I do not know what

Comment: Can you open your browser and open http://localhost:8000/administration?term=desh see if you can see json?

Comment: no I do not see JSON, in header for example

Comment: can you change to `return response()->json($data);`? see if you query is successes?

Comment: unsuccessfully adding `$data`

Comment: what do you mean **unsuccessfully** ?

Comment: No change from the initial situation, with `json($data)`, same as above : the drop down list is blank.

Comment: Does anyone has a solution ?

Comment: @cfor did you get your solution? I am facing the same problem.